# Integrate omnet++4.6 with 5.1

Tags: version, omnet++, mismatch

I have a project run on the Omnet 5.1 and another in the omnet 4.6, this because it is mandatory for them to run in these versions. Have a way to integrate or communicate this projects ?

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should port the 4.6 model, to run on OMNeT 5.x and then use both model in the same runtime.

Comment: Yes, I imagined this. I'll try use the Ext Interface for my application. Tks